# How to manage state for multiple Select components in React

Tags: html, reactjs, react-hooks, html-select

I am trying to create a schedule table where employees can be assigned for different days using the React Select component. But, I am not sure how to manage each of their states individually as currently, they all take the same value when I change one option. Any sort of guidance will be appreciated. Should I track each state separately? Wouldn't that get cumbersome?

**Here is my Table component:**

```
import React from "react";
import Select from "react-select";
import { useState } from "react";

const options = [
  { value: "None", label: "None" },
  { value: "X1", label: "X1" },
  { value: "X2", label: "X2" },
  { value: "X3", label: "X3" },
  { value: "X4", label: "X4" },
  { value: "X5", label: "X5" },
  { value: "X6", label: "X6" },
];

const headers = ["", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday"];
const columns = [
  "Morning Up Stairs",
  "Morning Down Stairs",
  "Morning Parking Lot",
  "Lunch A",
  "Lunch B",
  "Lunch C",
  "Lunch D",
  "Afternoon Up Stairs",
  "Afternoon Down Stairs",
  "Afternoon Parking Lot",
];

const Scheduler = () => {
  const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState(null);

  const handleSelectChange = (selectedOption, rowId, header, colName) => {
    setSelectedOption(selectedOption)
    console.log(`Selected option: ${selectedOption.value}`);
    console.log(`Row ID: ${rowId}`);
    console.log(`Column name: ${colName}`);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            {headers.map((header) => (
              <th key={header}>{header}</th>
            ))}
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {columns.map((colName, index) => (
            <tr key={index}>
              <td>{colName}</td>
              {headers.map(
                (header, index) =>
                  index > 0 && (
                    <td key={index}>
                      <Select
                        options={options}
                        value={selectedOption}
                        onChange={(selectedOption) =>
                          handleSelectChange(
                            selectedOption,
                            index,
                            header,
                            colName
                          )
                        }
                      />
                    </td>
                  )
              )}
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
};
```

**This is how it looks currently:**
[image: Same value]

Comment: Thats very simple. Create individual component of each day. Than each component will have its on state.

Comment: Adding separate components might be a good start. However, you need to think about data in general. What is the end goal. As I assume you want to combine all these inputs together. In that case, you will need to have some upper state and those individual components will change it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to create a component for individual day select lists, and has state in this individual day component.

Have a look at this: https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-waterfall-pi918n?file=/src/index.js